# Python Pandas - Dynamic matching of different date indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have two dataframes with different timeseries data (see example below). Whereas Dataframe1 contains multiple daily observations per month, Dataframe2 only contains one observation per month.

What I want to do now is to align the data in Dataframe2 with the last day every month in Dataframe1. The last day per month in Dataframe1 does not necessarily have to be the last day of that respective calendar month.

I'm grateful for every hint how to tackle this problem in an efficient manner (as dataframes can be quite large)

```
Dataframe1
----------------------------------
date            A          B        
1980-12-31      152.799    209.132
1981-01-01      152.799    209.132
1981-01-02      152.234    209.517
1981-01-05      152.895    211.790
1981-01-06      155.131    214.023
1981-01-07      152.596    213.044
1981-01-08      151.232    211.810
1981-01-09      150.518    210.887
1981-01-12      149.899    210.340
1981-01-13      147.588    207.621
1981-01-14      148.231    208.076
1981-01-15      148.521    208.676
1981-01-16      148.931    209.278
1981-01-19      149.824    210.372
1981-01-20      149.849    210.454
1981-01-21      150.353    211.644
1981-01-22      149.398    210.042
1981-01-23      148.748    208.654
1981-01-26      148.879    208.355
1981-01-27      148.671    208.431
1981-01-28      147.612    207.525
1981-01-29      147.153    206.595
1981-01-30      146.330    205.558
1981-02-02      145.779    206.635
```

```
Dataframe2
---------------------------------          
date                C        D     
1981-01-13          53.4     56.5
1981-02-15          52.2     60.0
1981-03-15          51.8     58.0
1981-04-14          51.8     59.5
1981-05-16          50.7     58.0
1981-06-15          50.3     59.5
1981-07-15          50.6     53.5
1981-08-17          50.1     44.5
1981-09-12          50.6     38.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide a readable example, I prepared test data as follows:

*df1* - A couple of observations from January and February:

```
        date        A        B
0 1981-01-02  152.234  209.517
1 1981-01-07  152.596  213.044
2 1981-01-13  147.588  207.621
3 1981-01-20  151.232  211.810
4 1981-01-27  150.518  210.887
5 1981-02-05  149.899  210.340
6 1981-02-14  152.895  211.790
7 1981-02-16  155.131  214.023
8 1981-02-21  180.000  200.239
```

*df2* - Your data, also from January and February:

```
        date     C     D
0 1981-01-13  53.4  56.5
1 1981-02-15  52.2  60.0
```

Both dataframes have *date* column of *datetime* type.

Start from getting the last observation in each month from *df1*:

```
res1 = df1.groupby(df1.date.dt.to_period('M')).tail(1)
```

The result, for my data, is:

```
        date        A        B
4 1981-01-27  150.518  210.887
8 1981-02-21  180.000  200.239
```

Then, to join observations, the join must be performed on the
**whole month** period, not the exact date. To do this, run:

```
res = pd.merge(res1.assign(month=res1['date'].dt.to_period('M')),
    df2.assign(month=df2['date'].dt.to_period('M')),
    how='left', on='month', suffixes=('_1', '_2'), )
```

The result is:

```
      date_1        A        B   month     date_2     C     D
0 1981-01-27  150.518  210.887 1981-01 1981-01-13  53.4  56.5
1 1981-02-21  180.000  200.239 1981-02 1981-02-15  52.2  60.0
```

If you want the merge to include data **only** for months where there
is at least one observation in both *df1* and *df2*, drop *how* parameter.
Its default value is *inner*, which is the correct mode in this case.

Comment: Just for clarification: I want to align the observations in dataframe2 with the last daily observation of that respective month in dataframe1.

Comment: I corrected my answer. Now the alignment of data from *df2* is just to the **last** observation from each month in *df1*.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a sample dataframe, you can provide code for doing so.  Simply select a column as a list (step 1 and 2) and use that list to build the dataframe with code (step 3 and 4).

```py
import pandas as pd

# Step 1: create your dataframe, and print each column as a list, copy-paste into code example below.
df_1 = pd.read_csv('dataset1.csv')
print(list(df_1['date']))
print(list(df_1['A']))
print(list(df_1['B']))

# Step 2: create your dataframe, and print each column as a list, copy-paste into code example below.
df_2 = pd.read_csv('dataset2.csv')
print(list(df_2['date']))
print(list(df_2['C']))
print(list(df_2['D']))

# Step 3: create sample dataframe ... good if you can provide this in your future questions
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['12/31/1980', '1/1/1981', '1/2/1981', '1/5/1981', '1/6/1981', 
             '1/7/1981', '1/8/1981', '1/9/1981', '1/12/1981', '1/13/1981',
             '1/14/1981', '1/15/1981', '1/16/1981', '1/19/1981', '1/20/1981',
             '1/21/1981', '1/22/1981', '1/23/1981', '1/26/1981', '1/27/1981',
             '1/28/1981', '1/29/1981', '1/30/1981', '2/2/1981'],
    'A': [152.799, 152.799, 152.234, 152.895, 155.131,
          152.596, 151.232, 150.518, 149.899, 147.588,
          148.231, 148.521, 148.931, 149.824, 149.849,
          150.353, 149.398, 148.748, 148.879, 148.671,
          147.612, 147.153, 146.33, 145.779],
    'B': [209.132, 209.132, 209.517, 211.79, 214.023,
          213.044, 211.81, 210.887, 210.34, 207.621,
          208.076, 208.676, 209.278, 210.372, 210.454,
          211.644, 210.042, 208.654, 208.355, 208.431,
          207.525, 206.595, 205.558, 206.635]
})

# Step 4: create sample dataframe ... good if you can provide this in your future questions
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['1/13/1981', '2/15/1981', '3/15/1981', '4/14/1981', '5/16/1981',
             '6/15/1981', '7/15/1981', '8/17/1981', '9/12/1981'],
    'C': [53.4, 52.2, 51.8, 51.8, 50.7, 50.3, 50.6, 50.1, 50.6],
    'D': [56.5, 60.0, 58.0, 59.5, 58.0, 59.5, 53.5, 44.5, 38.5]
})

# Step 5: make sure the date field is actually a date, not a string
df_1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['date']).dt.date

# Step 6: create new colum with year and month
df_1['date_year_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['date']).dt.to_period('M')

# Step 7: create boolean mask that grabs the max date for each year-month
mask_last_day_month = df_1.groupby('date_year_month')['date'].transform(max) == df_1['date']

# Step 8: create new dataframe with only last day of month
df_1_max = df_1.loc[mask_last_day_month]
print('here is dataframe 1 with only last day in the month')
print(df_1_max)
print()

# Step 9: make sure the date field is actually a date, not a string
df_2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['date']).dt.date

# Step 10: create new colum with year and month
df_2['date_year_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['date']).dt.to_period('M')
print('here is the original dataframe 2')
print(df_2)
print()
```

[image]

[image]